# How do I send and receive data from/to a Java Program from Oracle APEX

Tags: java, json, rest, oracle-apex

I've got an Oracle APEX application, and a Java-side application. The Java client is the back-end and Oracle APEX is the front-end. Java will deal with most of the logic.

In APEX, I need to be able to send information (JSON?) to Java. When Java receives this information, it needs to process this data and return this new information back to APEX so that it can store it in its database.

I'm having difficulties figuring out how APEX to make the connection between Java and APEX, and how to return information back to APEX.

If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be marvelous.

Comment: Why can't you do the 'Java processing' directly inside the DB? Have you tried using a [RESTful Web Service](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r50/Restful%20Services/restful_services.html)?

Comment: @Cristian_I Thank you for taking the time to reply. The idea of the software architecture that we have to implement for a project - is that APEX is mostly the UI. The business logic has to happen in Java. 

I need to be able to send data, in JSON, to the Java client. But I am having difficulties figuring out how to send it.